# [Json][Java] Clueless into how to parse this text. Using a library

Tags: java, json

I've been assigned in my college to make an work without any preparation and i don't have any idea on how to use JSON correctly to read this:

```
{ "af": [
 ["a", "b", "0", "1"],
 ["0", "1"],
 [ ["a","#","0"], [a,0,b], [a, 1, a], ["b", 0,"a"], ["b", "1", "b"], ["0", "0", "0"], ["0", "1", "1"], [1,0,1], [1 ,1, 0] ]
 ["a"],
 ["1"]
 ]
}
```

I've tried looking into some examples in the internet but no clue into how to use this. I'm trying to make this assignement with java and i was using the Json library json-simple. Could someone help me ? Like really no clue. I'll keep searching more examples.

Mainly my problem would be that to "have" parts of this json i would have to use jsonObject.get("name of stuff"); but the only name i have to use in this function is the "af" ... and dammit i can't out-think this, is Af an array of arrays ? is it a List ? i'm kindda stuck in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json text is invalid, because it contains unquoted keys/values.

you have two ways to work with this bad formatted json text:

## First

you should first turn your json to a valid json that every *character(s)* or string should be placed in double quotes. i.e.

this is invalid : `[a, 1 ,b]`

this one is valid: `["a", 1, "c"]`

*note: character(s) that i mentioned is anything except numbers*

then you can call `jsonArray.getJsonArray(n).getJsonArray(m)` recursively to get nested arrays where `n` and `m` are indices.

## Second

use [Jackson Core Library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core) features like `ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES` that allows you to parse json texts that are not quoted well. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15005293/4101906) too

Answer (score 0):

`af` is a json array, so you probably should use `jsonObject.getJsonArray("af")`. That would give you a `JsonArray` object which you can read using something like `jsonArray.getJsonArray(0).getString(0)` (you probably would need to find out the value types at runtime with `JsonValue.getValueType` though).

Comment: Wow thnks, that actually, really helps a lot men, real tnks i will try to run it here and get their values types.